# Violation of primarary key

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables `Asset` and `Inventory`, I created an intermediate table called `Asset_Inventory`

One or more assets can be in an inventory, and an inventory can be in one or more assets,but it does not allow me to insert data

Mistake

> The data in row 2 was not committed. Error source Message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT
> `PK_INVENTORY_ASSET`. Cannot insert duplicate key in object `dbo.Inventory_Asset`. The duplicate key value (1,1).

```sql
-- TABLE INVENTORY
GO
CREATE TABLE Inventory
(
    [inventory_id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [company_id] INT,
    [name] VARCHAR(50),
    [observations] VARCHAR(500),
    [date_created] DATETIME DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_INVENTORY_COMPANY FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(company_id)
)


-- TABLE ASSET
GO
CREATE TABLE Asset
(
    [asset_id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [company_id] INT,
    [code] INT,
    [model_name] VARCHAR(50),
    [model_number] VARCHAR(50),
    [serial_number] VARCHAR(30),
    [price] DECIMAL(10,2),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASSET_ID PRIMARY KEY(asset_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ASSET_COMPANY FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(company_id),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_ASSET_CODE UNIQUE(code)
)

--TABLE INVENTORY_ASSET
CREATE TABLE Inventory_Asset
(
    asset_id INT,
    inventory_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY_ASSET PRIMARY KEY (asset_id,inventory_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ASSET_ID FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES Asset(asset_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IVENTORY_ID FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory(inventory_id)
)
```

[image]

**UPDATED**

it's hard for me to ask this question

N companies have many assets; you need to have control over them. Have a list of assets by company, to which employee it was assigned, or in which department of the company that asset is located. a total of assets by company etc..

What is the purpose of this?

I need to physically label (bar code) each `asset` with a unique code
Cell phones, monitors, keyboards, servers, PCs, laptops, chairs, furniture, etc...

Once all the assets have been tagged in the
`company` `1`
`company` `2`
`company` `3`

I have to scan each code printed on the asset and make a monthly cut

I have to create a report with this information

In the `company` `1` an inventory was made in the month of January

Cut of the month of January:

- 20 monitors (10 dell , 10hp)
- 20 chairs
- 10 computers

the next month this cut is made again to see if there is the same quantity, if the 2 inventories of the month of January and February are not the same, some asset was stolen and to be able to identify this

an inventory can have one or more assets, and an asset can be in one or more inventories.

I think I can do this with the `Inventory_Asset` table

| asset_id | iventory_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |

**Am I wrong with my solution?**

```sql
--TABLE INVENTORY_ASSET
CREATE TABLE Inventory_Asset
(
    [inventory_id] INT,
    [asset_id] INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ASSET_ID FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES Asset(asset_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IVENTORY_ID FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory(inventory_id)
)
```

Comment: As you described, the PK on `Inventory_Asset` is (asset_id,inventory_id). This means you cannot have two rows with the same combination (1, 1) of values. Use different combinations like (1, 2) or (2, 1), or any other numbers.

Comment: What you describe is the expected behavior *in all databases*. You already specified that Inventory #1 is related to Asset #1. What are you trying to do? What did you expect?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated post, just added the result I expect

Comment: You're manually entering the values. It's up to you to enter the correct values

Comment: If you want (1, 1) on multiple rows, then that's NOT a primary key. Remove the primary key constraint `CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY_ASSET PRIMARY KEY (asset_id,inventory_id)` and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

```
CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORY_ASSET PRIMARY KEY (asset_id,inventory_id),
```

PRIMARY KEYS must be unique.  That is why you can't add this -- since it conflicts with your primary key.  If you don't want that to be unique but you do expect to use it as an index you can make an index that does not enforce uniqueness and make something else your primary key.

Comment: I must create another column to this table `Inventory_asset`

Telling it explicitly that it will contain an auto-incrementing numeric value, and I must define this field as pk?

if so, then `inventory_id` and `asset_id` I have to define them as fk right?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. *You* (or rather, your code) needs to specify the actual values it wants. The database can't guess by itself what inventory and what asset you want to combine

Comment: @I'mnewbie - you don't need to as long as there a unique column that can be used as the primary key.  If there isn't then you probably do want to create a new column to be the primary key for this table.  In some rare cases you don't need a unique primary key -- but honestly they are very rare.

Answer (score 1):

The answers and comments here are all correct; but perhaps we need to review *what* a many-to-many relation can be used for.

**Option 1: we just need a link between two entities**

This is what you have done. Basically it will serve if you want to know in which Inventories a given Asset is, which Assets a given Inventory holds, etc. In this scenario when you have established the link once (Asset 1 is in Inventory 1) there's no reason to re-establish it with further records.

**Option 2: we want to store some information about the relation**

This is what I suspect you really wanted. Suppose for instance you want to store how many Assets of type 1 are in Inventory 1. In this case what you want is to add a "Quantity" column to your `Inventory_asset` table. Once more, if there are 3 Assets of type 1 in Inventory 1 you won't duplicate the records: you will just create one record and put 3 in the new column.

**Option 3: we really need multiple records**

Suppose you want to store not only how many Assets of a given type are in a given Inventory, but also on which date a few of them were put there. So you may have 2 type 1 Assets put in Inventory 1 on May, 1st, and other 3 of them on May, 15th. In this case the date must become part of the PK, so that the system (and you too!) can distinguish between the different records. You may also decide to create an auto-increment column and use it as a PK instead; but note that while it may be simpler to handle, it would allow for unvoluntarily creating duplicate records, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: More or less is what you just raised me (I think so).
I just updated my post explaining my question better, it's hard for me to express what I want to achieve.

Comment: Ok, so Asset 1 is that single cell phone, and Inventory 1 is the monthly inventory for January for Company X, Inventory 2 is February's inventory for X, etc. Then why should you want to write more than once that Asset 1 is in Inventory 1? It seems that your _definition_ of the DB is correct, while your _input_ is wrong :)

Comment: **`your input is wrong :)`** where? the results of the tables?. I can't find the error


1 or x `inventory` can have one or more `asset`s, an example `asset`:
`asset_id=1, 
serial= 'A1B2C3-001'`
`asset_id=1
serial= 'A1B2C3-002'`

an asset can be repeated `cellular` in the same inventory

Comment: You cannot have two _different_ assets (i.e. two assets of same type with different serials) share the same `asset_id`, since `asset_id` is the primary key for the `Asset` table. They may be of the same type (and you may want to add a `asset_type` column perhaps) but they are distinct objects, both in the real world and in the DB. This is the very meaning of the concept of a Primary Key - a key which identifies a _single_ entity and hence a _single_ row

Comment: Otherwise, if you mean `asset_id` to be an identifier of the type of the asset, the PK will have to be (`asset_id`, `serial_number`) and of course the PK for `Inventory_asset` will need to change accordingly